# How can i make a column expand to the size of the enclosing row without it jumping on the next one?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's a video to illustrate since it's kinda hard to explain:

https://vid.me/tFdV

So i have this grid made with bootstrap and i'm trying to expand the cards to the width of the entire row when clicked.

So far i tried this with jquery by adding .col-sm-12 to the card but as you can see in the video it will mess up the order of the cards.

Now I've already tried to rearrange the cards using push and pull classes from bootstrap but to no avail.

I'd be glad for any pointers.

EDIT: now with 100% more code!

html:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-sm-pull-3">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            {{#each rave}}
                <div class="event no-padding">
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="card">
                            {{> ravePreview}}
                            <div class="card-content hidden">
                                {{> raveDetails}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.event {
  .make-xs-column(12);
  .make-sm-column(4);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.event-expanded {
  .make-sm-column(12);
}
```

js:

```
$(".event").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("event-expanded");
        $(".card-content", this).toggleClass("hidden");
    });
```

Comment: Do you have some code which demonstrates the structure of your site, and the current interaction behaviour? It's always more helpful when you include a [mcve], and makes it easier for users to devise a solution applicable to your situation.

Comment: if you'll attach the final HTML code i'll show You how to solve your problem :)